# Xamarin form google sign in authentication using firebase

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement Google sign-in feature for my Xamarin form application.
My Xamarin form project structure is like

```
-MySignInApp
-MySignInApp.Android
-MySignInApp.iOS
```

By using [this reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYMCrD9klA0), I need to install the NuGet packages below to `MySignInApp.Android`

```
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth
Xamarin.Firebase.Auth
```

I already set up and registered my application on google firebase, generated and download `google-services.json`.
The example above is using Xamarin native, my project is using Xamarin Forms and sharing the views.
I created `MainLogin.xaml` under `MySignInApp`. So the project structure will be like this.

```
-MySignInApp
     -...
     -Views
         -MainLogin.xaml
     -....
-MySignInApp.Android
-MySignInApp.iOS
```

I added `Sign-in with Google` button in MainLogin.xaml, since this view is under `MySignInApp`, how can I reference installed NuGet packages?  The problem is I cannot install required packages to `MySignInApp` project, so I cannot take references.
The Nuget packages are not compatible with `MySignInApp` project.
The error that I get is

```
Package Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth 119.2.0.2 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
```

How can I fix it? Does anyone encounter this issue?
Is there any way to implement Firebase Google SignIn to Xamarin Forms ?

Comment: check this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/97f83a62-7bef-481b-a1af-d51ddd22d0ab/error-when-trying-to-add-nugget-xamaringoogleplayservicesads?forum=xamarincrossplatform

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT , the issue in this link is about `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads` and it's resolved by removing `xamarin.forms.maps`. But I don't have `xamarin.forms.maps` in my project.

Comment: my bad, have you try this nuget package?https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GoogleClientPlugin

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT, this plugin works, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this nuget package https://github.com/CrossGeeks/GoogleClientPlugin